# XQuartz quits within a few seconds

Tags: x11, xquartz

macOS Big Sur 11.4, MacBook Air (M1, 2020)

XQuartz (2.8.1) starts but it quits within a few seconds. There are no warnings or reports but it quits sientlty.

I re-installed XQuartz, reboot, and deleted some files such as .zsh_history and .Xauthority, but I'm still having the same problem.

Any suggestions?

[updated]

The error seems to be `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources//GLRendererFloat.bundle/GLRendererFloat: #2: No such file or directory`.

```
Jun 25 13:28:45 [username] com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.applefsplaceholder): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Jun 25 13:28:53 [username] com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Coalition Cache Hit: app<application.org.xquartz.X11.32649354.32649362(501)> [1085]
Jun 25 13:28:53 [username] com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100004.Aqua): Check-in attempt by unmanaged service: Xquartz.21483
Jun 25 13:28:53 [username] X11.bin[21325]: getattrlist failed for /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources//GLRendererFloat.bundle/GLRendererFloat: #2: No such file or directory
Jun 25 13:28:56 [username] com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.applefsplaceholder): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Comment: Check the system log for messages, and also check for crash reports in the Console app.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post and still haven't figured out what the problem is.

Comment: We need something from the MacOS logs, not X11's own 'internal' log.

Comment: Some have reported that this might be an issue with the Big Sur installation and that reinstalling it fixed the issue.

Comment: Clean installing solved eventually the issue! After re-installing, another error said .xinitrc had a problem and I deleted it. I'm not sure if the original error was because of MacOS or .xinitrc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some have reported that this might be an issue with the Big Sur installation and that reinstalling it fixed the issue.